# what is type of Set in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, set

I'm trying to change code javascript to typescript
In Home.tsx,

```
interface IState {
    mySet: ??; // what is type of Set??
    myNum: number;
    myStr: string;
    myArr: number[];
}
class Home extends Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            mySet: new Set([]);
        }

    }
}
```

what is type of Set??

Comment: @Phil - would that help with **typescript**?

Comment: I just write 'typeof Set' into ?? 
am I right?

Comment: So, where has you exhaustive research and attempts gone so far?

Comment: I tried 
1. string[]  <-- that was still error
2. typeof Set <-- was good

Comment: @안다희 I think in typescript you will need to specify the generic for the set. So it should be `Set<number>` or `Set<string>` or if you have a generic in `IState<T>` then it can be `Set<T>`

Answer (score 16):

By looking at the definition in typescript for set, you will find this interface:

```
interface Set<T> {
    add(value: T): this;
    clear(): void;
    delete(value: T): boolean;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: T, value2: T, set: Set<T>) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    has(value: T): boolean;
    readonly size: number;
}
```

The `<T>` means that a `Set` type will require a type parameter. You would specify this in your `IState` object like so:

```
interface IState {
    mySet: Set<number>; // type depends on what type you want to store obviously.
    myNum: number;
    myStr: string;
    myArr: number[];
}
```

If you don't care about the types (you probably should if you're using typescript), then you can simply pass `any` as the type parameter, and the set will operate as it would in standard javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Type of set is how you create the set , Example

```
let mySet = new Set<string>();
```

then type is

```
mySet : Set<string>
```